# Deploying and rolling back changes in an Availability Group database

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, snapshot

I'm looking for a solution or workflow. Here's how I used to do database deploys when using a stand-alone server:

- Create a snapshot of the production database
- Deploy changes
- Verify that the deploy was successful
- If the deploy was not successful, restore the database from the snapshot.

I would like to perform a similar process on a database in an Availability Group, but restoring from a backup or snapshot is not a desirable option because the database is fairly large and I'd have to take the database out of the AG first. Here's the ideal type of solution I am looking for:

- Suspend data movement in the AG
- Deploy changes to primary replica
- Verify that the deploy was successful
- If the deploy was not successful, rollback the primary replica to the LSN where we suspended data movement and restart synchronization.

Is there a practical way of doing this?

I would use `BEGIN`/`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`, but this is harder to implement with the automated build process, and given that I would first like to inspect the results (from a different database connection) before committing or rolling back.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really a practical method. I can really think of three ways of rolling back a failed deployment:

- `BEGIN \ ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`: Normally, this is what I'd recommend - it's cleanest, and you wouldn't have to suspend data movement to do it. However, since you need to be able to view the changes from another machine, it's not really an option.
- Rollback script: With this, you pre-script the commands required to return the database to the state it was in prior to the deployment. It's not a true rollback, and it may be impractical on a large database in some circumstances.
- `RESTORE DATABASE`: As you mentioned, there are hassles for this on a large database in an AG.